# AWS SDK | List of waiters for Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sdk, boto

I'm interested in this [method](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.get_waiter) `get_waiter(waiter_name)`. Examples of waiters are in this [page](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/clients.html#waiters). I looked everywhere but I couldn't find a complete list of waiters for this particular service (for Python and PHP as well).

Basically, what I want to happen is to get the status of app or environment and verify it's good before moving on to the next task.

My current approach is to use `while` loop and `break` if the status from AWS response matches the status that I was expecting. I think this is not the best way to deal with this. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Here's the snippet from my code written in Python:

```
# Check the application status
while True:
    try:
        response = eb.describe_application_versions(
            ApplicationName=app_name,
            VersionLabels=[
                new_app_version
            ]
        )
        status = 'PROCESSED'
        app_status = response['ApplicationVersions'][0]['Status']

        if status == app_status:
            print('Application Status:\t', app_status)
            break
    except:
        raise

# Deploy the app to Elastic Beanstalk
try:
    response = eb.update_environment(
        ApplicationName=app_name,
        EnvironmentId=env_id,
        VersionLabel=new_app_version
    )
except:
    raise

# Check environment health
while True:
    try:
        response = eb.describe_environment_health(
            EnvironmentId=env_id,
            AttributeNames=[
                'Status'
            ]
        )
        status = 'Ready'
        env_status = response['Status']

        if status == env_status:
            print('Environment Status:\t', env_status)
            break
    except:
        raise
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no waiters for that service yet. If there were, you would see them in the docs. For example compare the [elasticbeanstalk boto3 docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html) with the [cloudfront docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html). The cloudfront docs have a [waiters section](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#waiters).